# Calculating a page number from list of IDs

Tags: c#

I'm paging some data, and I have a list of `long`s that contains the IDs of each element in the dataset. For now, I have something like this:

```
List<long> TheListOfIDs = {23,435,6635,4224,546,756,23,542....};
```

`TheListOfIDs` actually contains thousands of IDs. Each page of data contains 20 elements. I'm writing a function that receives a `long` and returns the page number on which the ID is. In the sample data for instance, ID number `435` is in second position so it's part of the first 20 elements and therefore it's on page 1.

If I write

```
int ThePageNumber = TheListOfIDs.IndexOf(TheID) / 20;
```

is this going to work in all cases?

Update edit: each element in the list is unique and the ID passed in the function is in the list for sure!

Comment: I don't know, but I upvoted to offset it. This isn't a poor question, by any means.

Comment: For duplicate cases like 23, No.

Comment: @YasserZamani: I have specified; each element in the list is unique and exists.

Comment: @JamesJohnson _"This isn't a poor question, by any means"_ A little "what have you tried" and explaining what cases are in "is this going to work in all cases?" is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write the unit tests of the different cases. The ones I have in mind are:

- First of first page
- Last of last page
- Middle of first page
- First of middle page
- Last of middle page
- Middle of middle page

If your code passes those tests, I think you are ok.

Comment: Indeed, but at the moment I'm looking to write the implementation.

Comment: Also, it seems you want people to do your work. My advice (beside you didn't ask for one) is to write the tests and make the code work instead of expecting StackOverflow to give you the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the case in which the id does not exist in the list of id.
Here is Java code:

```
public int getPage(List<Long> ids, Long id)
{
    int index = ids.indexOf(id);
    if (index == -1) 
        return -1; // the id does not exist in the list
    return (index / 20) + 1; // the page number should start from index 1
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks; I posted an edit: the ID passed in the function is in the list for sure.

Comment: If the list contains only unique elements and the key exists in the list, your expression is true. One more thing, I think the page number should start from index 1. Just add 1 to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Using [MoreLinq](http://morelinq.googlecode.com/).[Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs):

```
var pagebatches = TheListOfIDs.Batch(20);
```

Elements of pagebatches contain up to 20 items. Each item corresponds to a page number.

The last element of pagebatches may contain the remaining items (<=20).

Comment: I know of MoreLinq but I'm not going to using this library.

Comment: Well, if you dont want to reference the library, you can copy [Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) function, or make function similar to it that suits your purpose. Any specific reason for not using it.

Comment: Yes, it just adds a dependency and it's one more thing to think about so I'd rather avoid those if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You say position 2 is on page 1, but 2/20 = 0, so no, it won't work.

But you could do

```
int ThePageNumber = (TheListOfIDs.IndexOf(TheID) + NumIDsInEachPage - 1) / NumIDsInEachPage ;
```